# Conditional Statement custom post type category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I would like to display a text depends of my custom taxonomy category, like:

if *custom post type category* is *X*, then echo *Text Y*.

I've tried this, but its not working:

```
global $post; 
if (($post->post_type == 'myposttype') && is_category('slug-name-of-cat')) {
 echo 'My text'

 }
```

any ideias?

Comment: Try using `is_tax('taxonomy', 'term')` - [View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)

Comment: There's also a space in your "is _category." Should be "is_category". And double-check that slug's right. Did you really put "slug-" in your category slug?

Answer (score 4):

`is_category()` does not work on custom taxonomy archive pages. The correct conditional tag here is [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) which takes the name of the taxonomy as first parameter and a string|int|array of term name/s, slug/s or ID/s as second parameter.

So your whole conditional statement can look something like :

```
if ( is_tax( 'my_taxonomy', 'slug-name-of-the-term') ) {
    echo 'My text';
}
```

### EDIT

In addition, to test whether a post belongs to a specific term, you should use [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) to test for the specific term

```
global $post; 
if (    ( $post->post_type == 'myposttype' ) 
     && has_term( 'slug-name-of-the_term', 'my_taxonomy' )
) {
    echo 'My text';
}
```

Comment: Still need a semi-colon after that echo line.  ;-)

Comment: the "edit" version worked for me

Answer (score -1):

The conditional `is_*` functions work on query, not on current post. In other words they tell you things about page you are on, however not about the current post.

- [`is_category()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_category/) will check if current page is category archive
- [`has_category()`](http://queryposts.com/function/has_category/) will check if post has specific category assigned

From your description I suspect you mean the latter.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to this codex for detailed understanding:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

You can do something like this:

```
        $args = array(
                'taxonomy'     => **$your_taxonomy**,
                'orderby'      => name,
                'title_li'     => $title,
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args );
        if( !empty($sub_cats) ) {
         // echo our stuff
        }
```

Comment: You are completely on the wrong road here. I would love to see some kind of explanation that explains why you would want to use `get_categories`